# Selenium in Python How use a If - else code if an element is not present

Tags: python, selenium

All,  I am in need of some serious " dumbed down " examples of how to write code in Python that will do something if a element is there or not there. I'm new to programing and I have reviewed a days worth of posts and I can't seem to figure it out....

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, staleElementReferenceException

    elem = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Create Activity')

    print("Searching for Create Activity.")

    if elem.is_displayed():
        elem.click() # this will click the element if it is there
        print("FOUND THE LINK CREATE ACTIVITY! and Clicked it!")
    else: 
        print ("NO LINK FOUND")
```

So, Providing that there is a LINK present that is element_by_partial_link_text('Create Activity')

I get the proper response ...
Searching for Create Activity.
FOUND THE LINK CREATE ACTIVITY! and Clicked it!

My problem is when there is NOT a link that Matches `element_by_partial_link_text('Create Activity')`

I don't get what I would expect that is in my else statement.
 `print ("NO LINK FOUND")`

I get ...

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 341, in find_element_by_partial_link_text
>           return self.find_element(by=By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
>         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 745, in find_element
>           {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
>         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
>           self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>           raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Create Activity"}

How do I get selenium within `Python` to turn this exception or error to not halt my script and just process the `ELSE` statement.

Thanks,

Comment: You could use `try` and `except` statements?

Comment: what probably happens is that `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Create Activity')` returns `None` and the `elem.is_displayed()` throws a `NoSuchElementException`. There are many things you can do as for example: `if elem:` and then the `if elem.is_displayed()` or a `try-except` block

Comment: Best way to use `find_elements` and check size of elements instead of exception caching, see provided answer...:)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can catch the exception and act accordingly:

```
try:
    elem = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Create Activity')
    if elem.is_displayed():
        elem.click() # this will click the element if it is there
        print("FOUND THE LINK CREATE ACTIVITY! and Clicked it!")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("...")
```

Also, I would probably modify the test to make sure that the element is indeed "clickable":

```
if elem.is_displayed() and elem.is_enabled():
```

Answer (score 10):

`find_element` returns either element or throws `NoSuchElementException`, So for best way to determine element is present with if condition, You should try using `find_elements` instead of catching exception because it's returns either list of `WebElement` or empty list, so you just check its length as below :-

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Create Activity')

if len(elems) > 0 and elems[0].is_displayed():
    elems[0].click()
    print("FOUND THE LINK CREATE ACTIVITY! and Clicked it!")
else: 
    print ("NO LINK FOUND")
```

Answer (score -1):

Even simpler than try/except is just use find_elements(). If not present, it will return empty list. If not empty, clink of first found: found[0].click()