# Keys.BACK_SPACE or Keys.TAB send key is not working on facebook selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing some selenium code to navigate Facebook.

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def driver():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://facebook.com")


def chrome_options():
    global chrome_options
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
    # chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
    prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])


def actions():
    global actions
    actions = ActionChains(driver)


def login():
    try:
        # I use environment veriable  base on this tutorials https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IolxqkL7cD8
        username = os.environ.get('my_facebook_username')
        password = os.environ.get('my_facebook_password')

        driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_name("pass").send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()
        print(input("Press any Key: "))
        print("Login work Successfully ")

    except:
        pass


def navigatePagePostAria():
    sleepTime = 4
    implicitlyWaitTime = 20
    for i in range(2):
        driver.implicitly_wait(implicitlyWaitTime)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 4)
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        actions.perform()
        print("Firast 10 tabs Working")

    actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 3)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    actions.perform()
    print("Navigate Post area Successfully ")


chrome_options()
driver()
login()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/groups/402353916617590/permalink/1630582000461436/")
navigatePagePostAria()
```

Error Come from last function navigatePagePostAria()
The Line will be **actions.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)**

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\Project\Python\Miracle\groupPost.py", line 154, in <module>
    navigatePagePostAria()
  File "K:\Project\Python\Miracle\groupPost.py", line 63, in navigatePagePostAria
    actions.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

This two line is the most important like for navigation

**1.actions.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)**

**2.actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 4)**

I use that as a alternative of x path bechouse facebook is very dynamic its change its x path every minits.

**Video Description of my Problem:**
https://youtu.be/BzSBLAaYS-s

Comment: i think you need to find the element you are sending these keys to

Comment: Also implicit waits don't work that way and chrome_options are depreciated.

Comment: what is solution @ArundeepChohan

Comment: driver.back() goes back a page btw.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I don't want to go back. I want to go post area using keyboard operation using the TAB key. that's why I am using actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 4)

Comment: @NikolayPatarov I am using normal Keybord operation like we use in normal world. actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 4) means I want to use 4 time tabes for my navigation.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan ,  do you have more ideas to share?

Comment: pyautogui lighbary can be a solution. we can combine it with selenium.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mouse-keyboard-automation-using-python/

Comment: Use TAB until You Find the elements

Comment: https://www.pylabz.com/2019/08/testing-flash-app-using-pyautogui-in.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385221/send-multiple-tab-key-presses-with-selenium

Comment: Using Display logic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147245/selenium-in-python-how-use-a-if-else-code-if-an-element-is-not-present/39147358

Comment: This is the group I request to join https://www.facebook.com/groups/156177901453298/ , https://www.facebook.com/groups/256655817858291/, https://www.facebook.com/groups/952058104841002/ , https://www.facebook.com/groups/570227323001088/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using misleading names for your methods.
You defined the following method

```
def actions():
    global actions
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
```

so that now when you calling `actions.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)` the interpreter thinks you are calling that `actions` method, not the `actions` object initiated inside it.
I would recommend you define this method as following

```
def set_actions():
    global actions
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
```

or even better not defining this method at all since this is not really method you are going to call several times.
The same about `chrome_options` and `driver` methods.
There is no need to define them as methods since these are not reusable methods, it could better be a flat code, so that the entire your code will look as following:

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#Setting the chrome_options
global chrome_options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
# chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

#Setting the Chrome Driver
global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)

#Setting the Actions
global actions
actions = ActionChains(driver)


def login():
  driver.get("https://facebook.com")
    try:
        # I use environment variable  base on this tutorials https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IolxqkL7cD8
        username = os.environ.get('my_facebook_username')
        password = os.environ.get('my_facebook_password')

        driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_name("pass").send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()
        print(input("Press any Key: "))
        print("Login work Successfully ")

    except:
        pass


def navigatePagePostAria():
    sleepTime = 4
    implicitlyWaitTime = 20
    for i in range(2):
        driver.implicitly_wait(implicitlyWaitTime)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 4)
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        actions.perform()
        print("Firast 10 tabs Working")

    actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 3)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    actions.perform()
    print("Navigate Post area Successfully ")


login()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/groups/402353916617590/permalink/1630582000461436/")
navigatePagePostAria()
```

I also migrated the `driver.get("https://facebook.com")` into the `login` method since this belongs there more that to the basic initialization of the selenium webdriver itself

Comment: https://github.com/sushen/MiracleExperiments/blob/master/main.py

is working.

If I don't run Crome_Option Function It will not store browser data.

So I need to run the function and its works fine.

Can you consider run main.py and tell me where I miss understood?

Comment: I really want to help you with this too, unfortunately I have no Python installed neither on my private computer nor on my work laptop. I coded automation with Python last time more than 3 years ago... I will try to set it up, but can't promise that.

Comment: I face the problem from a different angle you might answer it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614276/perform-and-reset-actions-in-actionchains-not-working-selenium-python

Comment: I saw that. Currently I have no idea what is the issue there. You know, there are a lot of users here, not everyone knows everything. Moreover, if I could catch the problem with some  particular code, it doesn't say I will know what the problem with some other code. The same with most other users here, I guess.

Comment: But I really will try to find the problem and help you if I will be able.

Comment: Can I contact you personally? https://www.facebook.com/sushen.biswas/ this is my Facebook profile. I know I am asking a lot. Sometimes You 60 second to my 7 days. 

I promise I will not going take much time.

Comment: @SushenBiswas I've sent you a message there via a messenger

Comment: I got your massage.