# perform() and reset_actions() in ActionChains not working selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

This is the code that habe no error:

**perform() and reset_actions()**

but these two functions have to work combinedly

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import random

# Setting the chrome_options
global chrome_options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

google_search = [
    "1.' driver.switch_to.active_element' ",
    "2.this code is a one of important snippet for facebook automation.",
]

random_google_search = random.choice(google_search)

# Setting the Chrome Driver
global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)

# Setting the Actions
global actions
actions = ActionChains(driver)  

    
#the loop Running
def navigation():
    time.sleep(5)
    actions.reset_actions()

    driver.get("https://google.com")

    actions.send_keys(random_profile_post)

    total_tab = 3
    sleep_time = 1
    implicitly_wait_time = 4

    actions.reset_actions()
    driver.implicitly_wait(implicitly_wait_time)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

    for i in range(total_tab):
        actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
        print("Pressing * " + str(i + 1) + " * No Tab")

    actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    actions.perform()


for i in range(10):
    navigation()
    print("Pressing * " + str(i + 1) + " * st navigation function")
```

I am working with **navigation()** functions:

in the loop area

**actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)**

**actions.reset_actions()**

I need to reset action but it's not reseating previous preform()

What will be the batter way to do that.

[Please watch the youtube video for more clear understanding.](https://youtu.be/_jR9IldgacQ)

Comment: "I need to reset action but it's not reseating previous preform()" -- what do you mean by this? What are you expecting that's not happening?

Comment: Also in your loop you have `actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
        actions.reset_actions()` -- for one thing it doesn't look like that tab is ever performed.

Comment: @C.Peck it perform when finish the loop 

    actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    actions.perform()

Comment: Yes, that's what the code says right? I'm still not sure what the problem is

Comment: @C.Peck please watch the video I reord and add below the post

Comment: Why define a global `actions` to reuse and potentially cause problems like this? Would it be a problem to define a new `ActionChains` when you need one?

Comment: @C.Peck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67564250/keys-back-space-or-keys-tab-send-key-is-not-working-on-facebook-selenium-python/ I solve the issue before. I am fochasing on new problem.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is fixed already but will be in the next releases. Check the issue [#6837](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6837) in the github.

For now you can use temporary solution.

```
def perform_actions():
    """ Perform and reset actions """
    actions.perform()
    actions.reset_actions()
    for device in actions.w3c_actions.devices:
        device.clear_actions()


# the loop Running
def navigation():
    time.sleep(5)

    driver.get("https://google.com")

    actions.send_keys("A")

    total_tab = 4
    sleep_time = 1
    implicitly_wait_time = 4

    # actions.reset_actions()
    driver.implicitly_wait(implicitly_wait_time)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

    for i in range(total_tab):
        actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
        print("Pressing * " + str(i + 1) + " * No Tab")

    actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    perform_actions()
    print()
```

Comment: What is w3c_action?

Comment: the GitHub issue you refer its comes from 2019 and more than 2 years old. Can you look again?

Comment: Try latest 4.0.0.b3 version.

Comment: Not working https://github.com/sushen/MiracleExperiments/blob/master/3.FacebookGroupPostBot.py
Tested.

Comment: I didnt find     
for device in actions.w3c_actions.devices:
        device.clear_actions()
clear_actions() in hole documentation where you find it.

Comment: In source code. It’s just an example workaround but better to use dedicated ActionChains class or use the latest beta version

Comment: Can you have a minute? It will be very helpful if you have some time for me this is my https://www.facebook.com/sushen.biswas/ profile.

Answer (score 2):

You can just instantiate it inside the function. If this does not work you can try to throw it all inside `def`, aside from the `global` lines, which should be deleted.

```
#the loop Running
def navigation():
   actions = ActionChains(driver) 
.
.
.
```

Comment: It's hard for me to tell where exactly is the corner, but when there is a driver.get() inside a loop one has to be careful. Please consider also a driver.quit() at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You should store ActionChains in a variable, so you can store you action in a object.

```
def navigateGroupPostBtn():
    navigateGroupJoinBtnActions = ActionChains(driver)
    total_tab = 23
    sleepTime = 1
    implicitlyWaitTime = 20

    time.sleep(sleepTime)
    for i in range(total_tab):
        driver.implicitly_wait(implicitlyWaitTime)
        navigateGroupJoinBtnActions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
        print("Pressing * " + str(i + 1) + " * No Tab")
    navigateGroupJoinBtnActions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    navigateGroupJoinBtnActions.perform_actions()
    print("Navigate Groum Join Btn Successfully ")
```

**navigateGroupJoinBtnActions = ActionChains(driver)**